# quantum espresso installation

Tags: command-line, compiling, vlc, gcc, make

I got this on the terminal after I try to install quantum espresso

```
./configure: line 66: make: command not found
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking ARCH... x86_64
checking setting AR... ... ar
checking setting ARFLAGS... ... ruv
checking for gfortran... no
checking for g95... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for ifort... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgfortran... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for ftn... no
checking for nagfor... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for f90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pghpf... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for g77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for f77... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for cf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking whether the Fortran compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/chemistry/qe-6.4.1':
configure: error: Fortran compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: “checking whether the Fortran compiler works... no” Have you read the error messages? Have you installed a Fortran compiler on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

The output indicates that the make command is not installed nor any Fortran compiler. To install those, please run:

```
apt-get install -y build-essential gfortran
```

build-essentials is basically a meta package for all tools that are normally required to build anything from source files.